# Default font - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I want to make Times New Roman the default font on my Windows 7 machine. I can find how to change fonts, but not how to set a default font. Does anyone know, please?

Answer (score 0):

Most every program has its own handling of fonts and defaults. Windows can only set the font for Windows dialogs and displays, but not for other programs (like Word or Excel).

So it is not possible.